# calling SQLDB Bluemix service in Spring Application

Tags: sql, spring, ibm-cloud

I have a sample Spring application for registering the student. I even created a SQLDB Service using Bluemix. I am unable to bind the service in the spring application in Jpacontext.xml.

If someone could please help me in providing the syntax how to call that would really help me.

Comment: Do you have any code written yet?

Answer (score 1):

The following entries in server.xml enabled me to connect my Spring application to SQLDB Service instance running in Bluemix.

I kept db2jcc4.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar in shared/db2 folder.

Please look at the credentials for SQLDB instance in Bluemix to get the database instance name, username, password and host ip address.

```
<jdbcDriver id="DB2JDBCDriver" libraryRef="DB2"/>

  <library id="DB2" name="DB2 Shared Library">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/db2" includes="*.jar"/>
  </library>

  <dataSource id='MyDataSource' beginTranForVendorAPIs="false"   jdbcDriverRef="DB2JDBCDriver" jndiName="jdbc/MyDataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
  <properties.db2.jcc id='MyDataSource-props' currentLockTimeout="10s"
            databaseName='<Database instance name>' 
        password='<password>' 
        portNumber='50000' 
        serverName='<host ip address>' 
        user='<username>'/> 
<connectionManager connectionTimeout="10s" maxConnectionsPerThread="10" maxPoolSize="25" minPoolSize="5"/>
</dataSource>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I think we need more information to be of any real value, however, it may be helpful to begin by reviewing the link below which discusses the SQLDB service

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html#cli

and the following link which discusses how to bind to a service in Bluemix.

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/reqnsi.html#config

If you still have problems after reviewing this material, then please provide a code snippet and the errors you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to sqldb as JNDI resource. See more details on this here:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/178223/how-to-connect-to-db2-with-spring/

Taken from the link, example:

datasource-config.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/[some-jndi-name-from-server.xml]" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:WEB-INF/datasource-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

basically what you need is JNDI name to refer, from server.xml path in your application:

Dashboard -> Your application -> Logs and Files -> app -> .liberty -> usr -> servers -> defaultServer -> server.xml

Than it's possible to refer to your "dataSource" bean in application.